# Eclipse EAR Export Bug

Tags: eclipse, export, facelets, ear, jboss-4.2.x

I'm exporting an EAR project with Eclipse default exporter (right-click > Export > EAR File).

In the generated .ear file, some files have last modified date greater than effective last modified date on the file system. The discrepancy is about 2 hours and 20 minutes forward. 
E.g. file home.xhtml on file system has last modified date 30/05/2017 14.00, then in the ear the same file has last modified date 30/05/2017 16.22.

So, when I've deployed the ear, I've been involved in an error like this

> [STDERR] May 30, 2017 2:48:08 PM com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet
>   refresh   INFO: Facelet[/home.xhtml] was modified @ 2:48:08 PM,
>   flushing component applied @ 2:48:05 PM

In web.xml I've facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD set to 2. I could solve the problem setting it to 0. But the real problem is why Eclipse adds 2 hours to last modified date of file during ear export.

I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600

Any suggestion was appreciated.